# How to obtain the raw number value stored in the QJSValue object directly?

Tags: c++, qt

According to the documentation, the `QJSValue::toNumber()` method "has side effects on the script engine".

Assuming that `QJSValue::isNumber()` returns `true`, how can I obtain the raw number value stored in the `QJSValue` object without said side effects?

Comment: You can't.  This is just the way Javascript works.  If you have an object that happens to hold an integer, then you have to call method functions to get the value.  QJSValue is just exposing that same capability.  If it's an integer variable, then there is no extra function call to get the value.

Comment: @tim-roberts I know how JS works, but we are talking not about JS, but about C++.

Comment: Not really.  You are talking about a C++ library that is interfacing to Javascript.  The implementation of QJSValue is communicating with the Javascript interpreter.  Qt doesn't own the object.  Javascript does.  The caution there is thanks to the Javascript.

Comment: @tim-roberts How is it that "Qt doesn't own the object"? JS interpreter is part of Qt.

Comment: @Bogudan That's the point: the Javascript interpreter is *part* of Qt, it's not Qt. As the documentation explains, QJSValue is a *container* for a data type that is intended to exist within the javascript "realm". There's no "raw value", there is only the value that the javascript interpreter holds when the object is created. Are you trying to check whether a value was originally "set" as integer or float? If that's the case, you cannot do it: numbers are always float in JS, even if their values are considerable integers (`1.0 == `1`); since QJSValue holds a JS type, you'll always get a float.

Comment: Qt can't see inside the Javascript object.  It has to ask the Javascript interpreter for information through its defined APIs.  Those APIs are bound by Javascript's rules.

Comment: @musicamante, I need the raw numeric value without causing any side effects. Whether it's float or integer is separate question of converting said raw value later. Also, can you, please, explain what you mean by "the Javascript interpreter is part of Qt, it's not Qt"? Because I still don't understand how something can be part of Qt but not be owned by Qt.

Comment: @Bogudan I understand your confusion, but you have to consider that the JS engine is a further layer *within* Qt, following the precise rules of that language (most importantly, the fact that numbers are always doubles), treating them as different and non transparently communicable levels, if not for the provided functions like `toNumber()`. In that sense, Qt directly "owns" only the QJSValue object, not its value, because that value is only obtained by the JS interpreter. Trying an analogy, imagine a graphics editor that allows you to paint in it: while the OS may manage memory aspects »

Comment: @Bogudan » including "showing" what you paint in the program, the OS doesn't "own" the drawing, the program does. The program provides ways to let the OS access the drawing (banally, by exposing it to the screen), but the structural contents of the image are still managed by the program itself, following its own rules. If the program only uses vector drawing, the OS (or any possible API) cannot directly access that vector data, it can only "see" what the program allows, based on what the program can accept. JS can only have one possible value for a `Number` type, there's no "raw value".

Comment: @Bogudan Anyway, all the above is a bit abstract and probably unnecessary speculation; simply put: that's how it is, so there's nothing you can do about it and there's no point in digging into these aspects much further. What you should probably explain is: what are you *actually* worried about? If the value is created in JS and it's a standard `Number`, then nothing bad should happen. Do you have a specific case in mind which might create issues as mentioned in the docs? If so, please explain it, possibly by [edit]ing your question and provide a detailed explanation of your case.

Comment: @musicamante my question mostly comes from the performance investigation standpoint. As I see it, "has side effects on the script engine" means that in order to get the actual (raw) value, `QJSValue::toNumber()` method calls something within said engine that is not simple "return _value" statement.

Comment: @Bogudan No. QJSValue contains the javascript object itself. How it's internally "stored" in terms of the memory access and internal pointers of the javascript interpreter is completely irrelevant: the JS API exposes javascript objects, that's it. `toNumber()` tells the engine to call `valueOf()` of the object, which is exactly what you'd get by doing that in javascript. The side effects mentioned are about the possible errors it may encounter if `valueOf()` raises an exception in the JS engine for non standard `Number` types. If you're using standard numbers, you've nothing to worry about.

Comment: @musicamante on the side note. If I try to call `valueOf ()` for a QJSValue object myself, I still get a QJSValue object. Therefore, `toNumber ()` during evaluation at some point must have some way to extract a non-QJSValue value from a QJSValue object...